# Prevent line-wrap in visualization bar chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

In this image it is possible to see that there is a line wrap in the text:
[Line wrap active on visualization bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBIBy.png)

How to prevent this?
The code of this chart is:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(courseprogressdata);

var options = 
{
    title: 'Progresso do curso',
    chartArea: 
    { 
        width: '50%' 
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'none' 
    },
    chart: 
    {
        subtitle: 'com valores de 0 a 1' 
    },
    hAxis: 
    {
        minValue: 0, 
        ticks: [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], 
        format: 'percent' 
    },
    bar: 
    {
        groupWidth: "90%" 
    },
    cssClassNames: 
    {
        headerCell: 'googleHeaderCell' 
    }
};

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('courseprogresschart'));

chart.draw(data, options);
```

courseprogress is an array with this data:

```
"[["curso","progresso",{"type":"string","role":"annotation"}],
["PJU",0.7893,"78.93%"],
["Fundgest-GRHN1A",0.1427,"14.27%"],
["asdzxc2",0.0387,"3.87%"]]"
```

[EDIT] I notice that the line wrap happens only on firefox...
On chrome, everything is OK, see:
[Line wrap on chrome are disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3iZp.png)

And just for more information, the content of googleHeaderCell css is:

```
.googleHeaderCell {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the following option...

```
annotations: {
  alwaysOutside: true
}
```

Comment: pretty much, not ideal, only other option would be to somehow adjust the axis min value to ensure there is enough room -- but adjusting to less than zero isn't good either -- or make the chart wider, etc...